# Обработка двух массивов в foreach

Tags: php, массивы

Всем привет! У меня такая проблема:

Есть 2 массива, которые перебираются через foreach одновременно. Далее мне нужно соединить элементы двух массивов в один так, чтобы первое значение 1-го массива соединялось с первым элементом 2-го массива , второе со вторым и так далее. И чтобы это соединение было только одно.
То есть элементы соединялись в один только равные по индексу

Первый массив $understand должен связывается с вторым $paradigm, в примере используется еще phpmorphy, так как необходимо изменение окончания у второго массива.

В переменную $d выводится готовое сообщение, но каждый элемент 1-го массива связывается с каждым из 2-го массива.

```
foreach ( $understand as $director_1 ) { 
    foreach($paradigm as $form) {

        if(!$form->hasGrammems('ВН') || !$form_1->hasGrammems('МР') || !$form->hasGrammems('ЕД')|| !$form_1->hasGrammems('ТВ') || !$form_1->hasGrammems('ЕД'))
            continue;

        $d = $director_1 .' '. $form->getWord() .' '.$k_object_2.' '. $form_1->getWord() .' '.$k_form_2;
        $d = mb_strtolower($d);
        $d = lcfirst($d);    
    }
}

echo $d ."<br />";
```

Comment: Покажите, что пытались делать самостоятельно и тогда обязательно поможем.

Comment: Обрабатывайте в цикле FOR, а не FOREACH.

Comment: @Denis640Kb, немного добавил.

Comment: @Akina, для того, чтобы использовать phpmorphy, необходимо перебирать через foreach.

Comment: Оба массива имеют одинаковую размерность?

Comment: @Quazimorda, да

Comment: @Gama, сейчас у вас foreach внутри foreach. Это не одновременный перебор обоих массивов. Это первый элемент первого массива сначала сравнивается со всеми элементами второго, потом, второй элемент первого массива со всеми элементами второго и т.д. Вам следует использовать один цикл for. Тогда к элементам обоих массивов сможете обращаться по счётчику цикла и переберёте элементы за один проход, ну и соберёте $understand[$i] с $paradigm[$i] да и положите в третий какой-то массив, который объявите до цикла.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если массивы подобного типа, то можно сравнивать ключи. 
Пример:

```php
<?php
$understand = array("a","b","c");
$paradigm = array("1","2","3");

foreach ( $understand as $key=>$director_1 ) {
    foreach($paradigm as $key1=>$form) {
        if ($key == $key1){
            $d = $director_1 . ' - ' . $form;
        }
    }
    echo $d . '<br>';
}
```

Результат:

```
a - 1
b - 2
c - 3
```

Пример с предоставленными массивами:

```php
$understand = array("собирать","работать","помогать");
$paradigm = array("метод анализа","дискуссия","вопрос");



foreach ( $understand as $key=>$director_1 ) {
    foreach($paradigm as $key1=>$form) {
        if ($key == $key1){
            $d = $director_1 . ' - ' . $form;
        }
    }
    echo $d . '<br>';
}
```

Результат:

```
собирать - метод анализа
работать - дискуссия
помогать - вопрос
```

Comment: и первый, и второй массив содержит строки

Comment: @Gama ну так добавьте тогда пример массивов. Как мы можем угадать это???

Comment: $understand = array("собирать","работать","помогать"); $paradigm = array("метод анализа","дискуссия","вопрос"); это к примеру

Comment: @Gama А чем тогда не устроил предложенный вариант?

Comment: @Gama добавил снизу пример с Вашими массивами - всё тоже самое.

Comment: @Denis640Kb, путём оперативных действий )) у автора удалось выяснить, что массивы имеют одинаковую размерность. Посему не стоит использовать foreach внутри foreach, так как в общем случае будет сделано n * n переборов элементов, где n - размерность массивов. Лучше пользовать цикл for и за один проход объединить элементы массивов с одинаковыми индексами. Кроме того, лучше поместить полученное внутрь третьего массива, ну или как у вас, выводить на экран в цикле.

Comment: @Quazimorda Так вроде автор указал в комментарии, что ему критично именно через foreach. Сделать через `for` гораздо проще, но отталкивался от требований автора. В массив поместить можно, это 2 секунды, но у автора опять-таки просто вывод. Просто корректировка кода на своё усмотрение не приветствуется в данном сообществе. Множество раз исключительно за это минусовали.

Comment: @Denis640Kb, по-моему, автор просто не представлял как ещё можно перебрать оба массива разом. Ваши аргументы мне понятны, хотя и прискорбно, что вы страдали за оптимизацию заданий авторов. Однако, n действий вместо n в квадрате - достаточный аргумент по переделке ))

Comment: Да, мне действительно важно выводить именно через foreach. Плагин, который я использую с for не работает(

Comment: @Gama надеюсь Ваша проблема решилась? )

Comment: @Denis640Kb, да, всем большое спасибо))